# How can i rewrite this code into a eventhandler

Tags: javafx

hi guys how would i change this into a event handler without using the arrow because i don't understand what it means

```
  btn.setOnAction(event -> {if (btn.getText().equals(current.getCorrectAnswer()))
    {System.out.println("correctAnswer");
    } else {System.out.println("wrongAnswer");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a lambda expression. Better learn what it is instead of rewriting it.

A documentation: [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

If your development environment is e(fx)clipse, you can put the cursor on the "->", press ctrl+1 and select "Convert to Anonymous class creation", then this

```
btn.setOnAction(event -> {
    if (btn.getText().equals(current.getCorrectAnswer())) {
        System.out.println("correctAnswer");
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("wrongAnswer");
    }
});
```

becomes this

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (btn.getText().equals(current.getCorrectAnswer())) {
            System.out.println("correctAnswer");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("wrongAnswer");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: like you can see is small button game if the right button is clicked the get correct or wrong answer how would i implement a scoring system??

Comment: You should accept this answer if it answers your question. As to the scoring system, that's a totally different question, create a new one.

Comment: ok no problem  but is easier to get it answered it or can you contact me ?